# Fabric Gateway SDK: how to check if a channel exists?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I invoke `Gateway#getNetwork(String)` with the name of a non-existent channel.

```
Network network = gateway.getNetwork("nonexistent-channel");
```

Despite printing a long stack trace from this line, the resulting Network object I get is non-null. Not sure if this matters but my Fabric blockchain is v1.4.9 - I'm unable to upgrade the version for now. I'm using Gateway SDK v2.2.2.

What is the rationale for this behavior? More importantly, how do I check in this case that I am calling a non-existent channel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the existing channels to get the list of all the available channels using the help of `CSCC` (Configuration system Chaincode).

```
const network = await gateway.getNetwork("mychannel");
const contract = network.getContract('cscc');
const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('GetChannels');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour is intentional as the client doesn't know whether the channel name you've supplied is a non-existent channel or one that actually does exist but simply isn't defined in the local connection profile.

When it comes to actually invoking transactions on chaincode deployed to that channel, of course it will fail if the named channel (or the chaincode, or the transaction function) doesn't actually exist.